# How can I get the nearest entity in python

Tags: python, pandas, math, pytorch, mss

My code:

```
from mss import mss
import math
import cv2
import numpy as np
import torc

with mss() as sct:
   monitor = {"top": 220, "left": 640, "width": 640, "height":640}    

while True:
    screenshot = np.array(sct.grab(monitor))
    results = model(screenshot, size=600)
    df = results.pandas().xyxy[0]
    distances = [] 
    closest = 1000
                      
       try:

          xmin = int(df.iloc[0, 0])
          ymin = int(df.iloc[0, 1])
          xmax = int(df.iloc[0, 2])
          ymax = int(df.iloc[0, 3])
          
          centerX = (xmax + xmin) / 2 + xmin
          centerY = (ymax + ymin) / 2 + ymin
          
          distance2 = math.sqrt(((centerX - 320) ** 2) + ((centerY - 320) ** 2))
          distances.append(distance2)
          if closest > distances[i]:
              closest = distances[i]
              closestEnemy = i
```

Only problem now is that it doesn't seem to get the closest enemy, is my math wrong? If my math should be wrong, how can I improve it? Also if my math is correct, how can I improve it in order to achieve my goal of getting the nearest entity? Any help will be very appriciated. Thanks in advance to everyone who invests his / her time in helping me :)

Comment: [mre] is required. please review [ask]

Comment: Hey @ChristophRackwitz, thanks for you awnser, which information is needed for you? I'll gladly add it.

Comment: if you need the math reviewed: ponder the meaning of `(xmax + xmin) / 2 + xmin` , you probably want something slightly different. -- MRE means MRE. this question lacks input data. you don't say what game it is, you don't provide screenshot data... your entire question doesn't explain anywhere what you're doing or why. you just jump into the problem, hoping that readers piece the puzzle together.

Comment: It's basically for a human detection software written in python. It works with mss and CV2 so you can have a live window where it shows the detection of the humans.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not entirely clear, what you are after... but my guess is, that there is a small mistake when calculating the center of the enemies. Either use:

```py
centerX = (xmax + xmin) / 2  # do not add xmin here
centerY = (ymax + ymin) / 2  # do not add ymin here
```

or calculate the distance between the minimum and maximum values and add the minim again:

```py
centerX = (xmax - xmin) / 2 + xmin  # subtract minimum from maximum
centerY = (ymax - ymin) / 2 + ymin # subtract minimum from maximum
```

**Additional remark:**
Performance wise it is mostly *not* a good idea to iterate over a pandas data frame. Another approach is to add a new column `distance` to the data frame and then search for the index of the minimum value:

```py
df['distance'] = (
    (( (df['xmax']+df['xmin'])/2 - 320) ** 2) + 
    (( (df['ymax']+df['ymin'])/2 - 320) ** 2)
    ) **0.5
         
closest_enemy = df['distance'].idxmin()
```